# nginx OpenREsty handle requests

Tags: angularjs, nginx, lua, openresty

I have a nginx server that acts like a proxy between , client and server . 
I am using Lua nginx Module ( open resty), front end technology ( Angular) . and web service is implemented in the server side

For some particular reasons , In the proxy i am managing to make some particulars calls and treatments .using Lua , I will make some code `access_by_lua_block {}`between the brackers
 . So I wast just thinking if I can access to the front of the server to retrieve some services , and models and treat them , Without calling the webservice again. 
In other way could I call a js from the proxy for example ?

Comment: any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Well After researches I ve just found the solution

Add this line

```
add_after_body /script.js;
```

in the conf file of nginx